# How to fail the RSpec test from inner block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is my code:

```
  operations_client.invoke_generic_operation(redeploy) do |on|
    on.success do |data|
      expect(data['status']).to eq('OK')
      expect(data['message']).to start_with('Performed [Undeploy] on')
    end
    on.failure do |error|
      fail 'error callback was called, reason: ' + error.to_s
    end
  end
```

However, the `expects` statements don't have any impact on the test result, it's simply ignored if it's not called on the "top lvl scope". I am Ruby noob, so please bare w/ me ;)

Note1: It's not a RoR app, it's a simple Ruby gem with RSpec.

Note2: I've extended the `Proc` class to be able to write these callbacks, here is the code, I've used:

```
class Proc
  def perform(callable, result)
    self === Class.new do
      method_name = callable.to_sym
      define_method(method_name) { |&block| block.nil? ? true : block.call(result) }
      define_method("#{method_name}?") { true }
      def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block) false; end
    end.new
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the `self === Class.new` thing all about? That's really irregular.

Comment: @tadman http://www.mattsears.com/articles/2011/11/27/ruby-blocks-as-dynamic-callbacks/ `===` calls the block and `Class.new` creates an anonymous instance

Comment: Interesting, but really not a very clear way of writing things, a victim of being too clever. I'm not sure how performant code using this method is, it seems loaded with overhead.

Comment: yeah, rubocop was complaining so I ended up with `call(Class.new do..` Performance is not big deal, since it's the test suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the block to capture the data and set the expectations afterwards.

```
actual_data = nil
operations_client.invoke_generic_operation(redeploy) do |on|
  on.success do |data|
    actual_data = data
  end
  on.failure do |error|
    fail "error callback was called, reason: #{error}"
  end
end

expect(actual_data['status']).to eq('OK')
expect(actual_data['message']).to start_with('Performed [Undeploy] on')
```

If you are using the newer RSpec 3.x, you can combine this into a single expectations:

```
expect(actual_data).to include(
  'status' => 'OK',
  'message' => start_with('Performed [Undeploy] on'),
)
```

However, your original version *should* work as you expect. Unless there is another state which is sent that is neither `success` or `failure`; thus neither the `expect` nor `fail` messages are sent. In that case there would be no expectation defined nor a failure so the spec would simply pass.

Also, it's not clear what `invoke_generic_operation` does. Is it possible it is swallowing any errors that are being thrown by the blocks? If so, that would cause issues as well. The capture method I've shown above would side-step that process. If this is what is happening, it's probably a good idea to comment that in the spec.

Comment: awesome, this works as expected. Unfortunately, the code is not blocking, so I have to use `sleep(5)` to wait for the result, but that's ok. I can wait less seconds if the VCRs are being used. Thank you! oh, and the `invoke_generic_operation` basically opens a web socket connection, sends a message and waits for the response from the server.